# Modified text appears to expose voting behavior

Tags: discussion, last-activity

Perhaps the circumstances are too specific for this to be a problem but I just noticed that you can tell how the last person to modify a post* voted if:

- They did not ask, answer, or edit the question or answers AND

  - They are the first person to vote OR
  - All votes are the same

Granted, you have to either have the privilege to see vote counts or be the person whose post was voted on to be sure of one of the last two but is this something that should be visible at all? Should a user who has just be down voted be able to look up their post in a list sorted by activity and get the user name who did it?

*To be clear, I'm not talking about just your *own* posts, though that would likely cause the most trouble. I noticed it here: [How can I delete a Stack Exchange account of mine?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267564/how-can-i-delete-a-stack-exchange-account-of-mine)

At the time I posted this question, it was modified by a user who had not edited the question or the answers, left an answer, or even left a comment. This means, unless there's another way to modify a post, that they voted on it. Since all of the votes on the question were up votes, it means they voted it up.

In this instance it was positive but should I be able to figure that out at all?

Comment: Where can you see that I down voted you?

Comment: I'm not kidding here, because I really don't understand where I have to look, at what sorted list. If it is hard to explain, maybe a screenshot can help me understand it.

Comment: @rene - If you look at posts [sorted by activity](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/active) you'll see who modified the post last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> At the time I posted this question, it was modified by a user who had not edited the question or the answers, left an answer, or even left a comment. This means, unless there's another way to modify a post, that they voted on it.

Your premise is wrong — up- and downvotes don't modify a question. What happened is that the user posted an answer, and deleted it shortly thereafter:

[image]

But, agreed, it's hard to see if you don't have the 10k required to see deleted posts.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. Unfortunately, that makes my question terrible.

Comment: Well, if it were worded like "how can this question be modified by a user that didn't seem to take an action on it", it'd be a lot better. In this case, assumption is the mother of all .......

Comment: It'd mess up the wording of your answer though; I'd have to get rid of the part you quoted. It wouldn't make it *wrong* but it'd still be messing up an existing answer after the fact, which I though was against the rules.

Comment: Also, if I'd asked it that way, I would have found the dupe. Assuming it had something to do with voting is what kept me from finding it.